# How to suppress Chrome DevTools warning: 'DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for...'

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

**Context**

For many of my js files I have no source map. When using the devtools console it pollutes the warnings about that. I would not like to turn of all warnings, but those are not really useful for me

**Question**

How to suppress Chrome DevTools warning:  'DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for...'?

Comment: I use a filter in the toolbar, https://puu.sh/FJo1m/eb54eab44e.png

Comment: Many thx. Could you please post as an answer, an also the filter expression in text form too I am  going to accept it.

Comment: A better way is to use DevTools to persist the suppression, I have put some screenshots in an answer to this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In DevTools (F12) -> Settings (F1) :

Disable **both** "enable JS source maps" and "enable CSS source maps" in "Preferences -> Sources"

Comment: This disables source maps altogether. While I guess its technically a solution, it removes important functionality at the same time. Its not about having NO source maps, its about just getting rid of the annoying warnings.

Comment: On mac os it is called:  "enable Javascript source maps"

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted solution... Removing source maps is not beneficial, just to silence warnings.

Answer (score 27):

Hide them via console filter like `-/(load|parse)\sSourceMap/`

[image]

<sup>(using a /regexp/ with \s seems to be the only working method of specifying strings with spaces)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to persist this? and/or be able to filter still?

Comment: True but if it's in there, I cannot filter by any other queries. Or rather I need to append another "minus" filter.

Comment: No, you'll have to use an external text/clipboard utility to quickly insert your snippets.

Comment: @Joe you can add multiple queries by separating them with a comma + space (e.g. `-query1, -query2`)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it only remove source maps warnings and not the whole source maps feature

Comment: In Chrome 108 the warning text is different, I used the filter `-/(load|parse)\ssource\smap/`.

Answer (score 7):

If you open DevTools (F12) then look for the cog "Preferences" top/right you can disable "Enable JavaScript source maps" under the Sources section by un-checking that option.

[image: Find the cog (preferences)]
[image: Find the option]

Comment: Disabling source maps is not a solution. Source maps are useful for developers, removing them is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is only if you don't want to use that particular extension (which is causing the issue) on your site or to remove the addon from your browser.

- Goto the console.
  [image]

Click on the link that is printedn in the console log. the link starts with "chrome-extension", it will take you to the extension's page, you can find the name in the address bar

[image: Screenshot of chrome extension]

Go to the extensions( `Chrome menu > More tools > Extensions` ).
You can either remove it from the browser or restrict the access by changing the site access to `On click` choosing from the options of the extension as below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Often, these messages are caused by other contexts, such as extensions or workers. You can make the console only show those messages, that originated from the selected context (e.g. `top`). 
Console tab -> Settings icon (top right) -> Make sure `Selected context only` is selected. 
[image: Console setttings]