# DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for GitHub. HTTP error: status code 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, github-pages, devtools

I made an ecommerce webpage. The code seems fine; but when I deployed it in my localhost and in GitHub it shows this error:

> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://andrealb88.github.io/rewards-store-andrea-lopez-bravo/static/js/main.51faf61f.chunk.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

I am new at this, and I read I need to fix it in DevTools. Do I need to install something to get rid of the HTTP error?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress Chrome DevTools warning: 'DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61746642/how-to-suppress-chrome-devtools-warning-devtools-failed-to-load-sourcemap-cou)

Comment: I tried to do that( enable js and css source maps) and nothing, the same 404 error. I can't see properly the page, neither the image of error

Answer (score 2):

This warning is probably nothing to worry about.  If you don't want to see it, you can disable it:  [Error message "DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339968/error-message-devtools-failed-to-load-sourcemap-could-not-load-content-for-chr?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, but I can not see the website, Only  the  picture with error 404.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this as well. [Here][1] I found the following:

> ...use the full link
> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@0.11.0/dist/hls.min.js the source
> map loads correctly.

This must be a bug in the npm package.
[1]: https://github.com/jsdelivr/jsdelivr/issues/18084